# listing directory recursively

Tags: c, recursion, directory, directory-listing

I'm failing at writing this function correctly. It should be listing recursively the content the path provided by the first argument (like ls -R), but it stops too soon. Here is the code, the expected output and the output I get:

```
int browseDir (const char *path, const int *options)
{
    char callingdir[MAXDIRLEN];
    char currentdir[MAXDIRLEN];

    getcwd(callingdir,MAXDIRLEN);

    DIR *dirstream;
    struct dirent *dir_entry; 
    struct stat file_data;
    LIST subd_list = newList();

    if (path == NULL)
        strcpy(currentdir,callingdir);
    else
        strcpy(currentdir,path);

    dirstream = opendir(currentdir);
    printf("Listing: %s\n",currentdir);
    chdir(currentdir);

    if (dirstream == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: cannot open directory\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while((dir_entry = readdir(dirstream)) != NULL)
    {
        if (!ISSET_A_FLAG(*options))
        {
            if (dir_entry->d_name[0]=='.')
                continue;
        }
        if (!ISSET_S_FLAG(*options))
        {
            stat(dir_entry->d_name, &file_data);
            printStat(&file_data);
        }
        printf("%s ",dir_entry->d_name);
        printf("\n");
        if (ISSET_R_FLAG(*options) && (dir_entry->d_type & DT_DIR) && strcmp(dir_entry->d_name,".") && strcmp(dir_entry->d_name,".."))
            addNode(subd_list, dir_entry->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dirstream);

    while(!isEmpty(subd_list))
    {
        browseDir((*subd_list)->data, options);
        delNode(subd_list);
    }

    chdir(callingdir);
    return 0;  
}
```

output using ls -Rli (expected)

```
tod@iTod:~/Dropbox/programming/SO/myshell2$ ls -lRi /home/tod/programming/shelldeb
/home/tod/programming/shelldeb:
totale 52
1150597 drwxr-xr-x 3 tod tod 4096 ott 18 02:34 bin
1054396 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod 7696 ott 18 15:21 commands.c
1045205 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod 1233 ott 16 23:14 commands.h
1045208 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod  952 ott 18 17:10 list.c
1057517 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod  244 ott 18 15:22 list.h
1055205 -rw-r--r-- 1 tod tod  487 ott 18 02:36 main.c
1150595 drwxr-xr-x 3 tod tod 4096 ott 18 02:34 obj
1057590 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod 1213 ott 18 09:33 parsing.c
1057622 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod  193 ott 18 09:33 parsing.h
1055154 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod 1368 ott 18 02:51 shelldeb.cbp
1057688 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod  665 ott 18 15:22 shelldeb.depend
1057721 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod 1413 ott 18 23:20 shelldeb.layout

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/bin:
totale 4
1150598 drwxr-xr-x 3 tod tod 4096 ott 20 14:02 Debug

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/bin/Debug:
totale 4
1150684 drwxrwxr-x 4 tod tod 4096 ott 20 14:02 r55

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/bin/Debug/r55:
totale 8
1150685 drwxrwxr-x 2 tod tod 4096 ott 20 14:03 tmpfolder
1150686 drwxrwxr-x 2 tod tod 4096 ott 20 14:02 tmpfolder2

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/bin/Debug/r55/tmpfolder:
totale 0
1045360 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod 0 ott 20 14:03 myfile

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/bin/Debug/r55/tmpfolder2:
totale 0

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/obj:
totale 4
1150596 drwxr-xr-x 3 tod tod 4096 ott 20 14:01 Debug

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/obj/Debug:
totale 20
1046334 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod 15088 ott 18 17:10 commands.o
1046232 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tod tod     0 ott 20 14:01 comment.txt
1150683 drwxrwxr-x 2 tod tod  4096 ott 20 14:02 tmpfolder

/home/tod/programming/shelldeb/obj/Debug/tmpfolder:
```

current output running my shell:

```
> list /home/tod/programming/shelldeb -r
Listing: /home/tod/programming/shelldeb
1057517 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000      244 list.h 
1054396 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000     7696 commands.c 
1057590 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000     1213 parsing.c 
1150597 drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000     4096 bin 
1045208 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000      952 list.c 
1055154 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000     1368 shelldeb.cbp 
1150595 drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000     4096 obj 
1045205 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000     1233 commands.h 
1057688 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000      665 shelldeb.depend 
1057721 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000     1413 shelldeb.layout 
1057622 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000      193 parsing.h 
1055205 -rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000      487 main.c 
Listing: obj
1150596 drwxr-xr-x  3 1000 1000     4096 Debug 
Listing: Debug
1046232 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000        0 comment.txt 
1150683 drwxrwxr-x  2 1000 1000     4096 tmpfolder 
1046334 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000    15088 commands.o 
Listing: tmpfolder
1054413 -rw-rw-r--  1 1000 1000        0 tmp.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without knowing how your code is going wrong, it's much more difficult than otherwise to offer useful advice on how to debug it; if you edit your question to include the output you get, and describe in some detail how it differs from what you intend, you'll be a lot likelier to get a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, I'm editing the code with new informations (since I've improved a little my code) and I'll add the output as well.

Comment: Try adding some debugging printf()'s to your code--e.g. at the entrance to your recursive function, and maybe listing out `subd_list` after each call to `browseDir` so that you can see why it is terminating early.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to write a recursive-listing function in a very simple way. I found the function nftw() in the c standard library, and basically it does all the work.
Here is the code for who can be interested:

```
static int list (const char *path) 
{
  char calling_dir[MAXDIRLEN];
  DIR *dirstream;
  struct dirent *dir_entry; 
  struct stat file_data;

  getcwd(calling_dir,MAXDIRLEN);  
  dirstream=opendir(path);

  if (dirstream == NULL)
    {
      perror("Error: cannot open directory\n");
      return -1;
    }
  chdir(path);

  while((dir_entry = readdir(dirstream)) != NULL)
    {
      if (!ISSET_A_FLAG(options))
    {
      if (dir_entry->d_name[0]=='.')
        continue;
    }
      if (!ISSET_S_FLAG(options))
    {
      stat(dir_entry->d_name, &file_data);
      printStat(&file_data);
    }
      printf("%s ",dir_entry->d_name);
      printf("\n");
    }
  closedir(dirstream);
  chdir(calling_dir);
  return 0; 
}

static int list_R (const char *entry_path, const struct stat *entry_stat,int typeflag,struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
  int status;
  if(typeflag & FTW_D)
    {
      printf("\nContent of %s : \n",entry_path);
      status=list(entry_path);
    }
  if (status == -1)
    return status;
  return 0;
}
```

with those two functions you just have to implement printstat() that prints infos on the directory entry.
A simple call to nftw(path,list_R,1,ftw_flags); after setting FTW_PHYS flag does the job.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a program like `ls` (that takes the directory path as it's only argument) then I think that you're over-complicating it , here's my version :

```
struct dirent *file = NULL;
DIR * direc = NULL;

if((direc = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
{
         perror("");
         exit(-1);
}
while((file = readdir(direc)) != NULL)
        printf("%s" , file->d_name);
```

and there you have it a basic working `ls` like program

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately my goal is to write an entire basic shell, with several features, including the ls (in this case called list) command. And the problem is only that I don't succeed in implementing the recursive listing list -r which should work as ls  -R.